# AutoRefresh on DynamicData and ReactiveUI

Tags: dynamic-data, reactiveui

I'm trying to observe when a value of IsEnabled in one of Results changes:

```
SourceList<Models.Result> mySource = new SourceList<Models.Result>();
var isEnabledChangedOperation = mySource.Connect().AutoRefresh(r => r.IsEnabled).Select(_ => TestFunction());
```

but "r => r.IsEnabled" is underlined and gets an error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'TimeSpan?' because it is not a delegate type"

What's wrong?

Comment: your sample code does not call `.Subscribe()` at the end. This is required to kick-off all of your rx code.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect most likely you didn't put `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your Result class.

I had the same error with your sample code until I added that.

Comment: Thanks.
I add and the project can be compiled.

But it still doesn't work.
`var isEnabledChangedOperation = mySource
                 .Connect()
                 .AutoRefresh(r => r.IsEnabled)
                 .ToCollection()
                 .Do(x => TestFunction());
`

TestFunction never fires.
I tried with `INotifyPropertyChanged` and with `ReactiveObject` but nothing has changed

Comment: Do you invoke the PropertyChanged event, in the IsEnabled setter? Something like: `set {_isEnabled = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsEnabled)));`
[Check out the unittest in the DynamicData source.](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/blob/master/src/DynamicData.Tests/AutoRefreshFilter.cs) @hooboe

Answer (score 0):

The solution without `AutoRefresh()`:

To add and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `ReactiveObject` to Models.Result 
and set:

```
var isEnabledChangedOperation = mySource
  .Connect()
  .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.IsEnabled)
  .Subscribe(x => TestFunction());
```